# Show average hours in specific periods using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, reportbuilder3.0, report-builder2.0

I am trying to display average vacation days and sick days for 3 periods.

So far I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT AVG(VACATIONHOURS) AS 'Vacation hours', AVG(SICKLEAVEHOURS) AS 'SICK DAYS'
FROM HUMANRESOURCES.EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.BIRTHDATE BETWEEN '01-01-1960' AND '12-31-1969'
UNION ALL
SELECT AVG(VACATIONHOURS) AS 'VACATION', AVG(SICKLEAVEHOURS) AS 'SICK DAYS'
FROM HUMANRESOURCES.EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.BIRTHDATE BETWEEN '01-01-1970' AND '12-31-1979'
UNION ALL
SELECT AVG(VACATIONHOURS) AS 'VACATION', AVG(SICKLEAVEHOURS) AS 'SICK DAYS'
FROM HUMANRESOURCES.EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.BIRTHDATE BETWEEN '01-01-1980' AND '12-31-1989'
;
```

My output only has 2 columns sick and vacation day and 3 rows under with numbers.

[image: Output picture]

My question is how to add a 3rd column that will show years?

I need that for report builder, so I can represent that information correctly

Comment: What do you mean by years? DO you want to write 1960 to 1969 in first row and so on?

Comment: I need to a add a third column that will indicate that 45 and 42 numbers are selected from year 1960 to 1969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are looking to add the year in the where clause then just add max(years)

```
SELECT AVG(VACATIONHOURS) AS 'Vacation hours', 
       AVG(SICKLEAVEHOURS) AS 'SICK DAYS', 
       max('1960 to 1969')
 FROM HUMANRESOURCES.EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.BIRTHDATE BETWEEN '01-01-1960' AND '12-31-1969'
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. I just don't understand how 'max' method works?

Comment: If you just use '1960 to 1969' you will get an error stating that not a group by function. So if you use an aggregate function like max or min you need not add a group by. In this case, Max(some string) and some string is same

Comment: I see, make sense . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you put these into groups.  I would just do:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(BIRTHDATE), 's') as decade,
       AVG(VACATIONHOURS) AS `Vacation hours`,
       AVG(SICKLEAVEHOURS) AS `SICK DAYS`
FROM HUMANRESOURCES.EMPLOYEE E
GROUP BY decade
ORDER BY decade;
```